# jquery clicking tr affects all rows even the thead row

Tags: jquery

Below is my code which works fine.  I can click on a row within a table and it does what I want it to.  The issue is that it also triggers on the `<TH>` and I can't figure out how to use something like `.not('thead tr')` with this function.  I need to turn the TH into a sort so I need to keep it from triggering on the row click.

```
$('#upgrades').on("click", "#upgrades tr", function () {
*** do stuff
});
```

Comment: Please include all relevant code

Comment: how  your html layout looks like ?

Comment: you can select with $('tr:not("thead tr")')

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try `":not(thead) tr"` - [`.not()`](https://api.jquery.com/not/)

Is this what you want? this does so you cant click on any `tr` in the `thead`

```js
$('#upgrades').on("click", ":not(thead) tr", function() { 
  console.log("clicked")
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="upgrades">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>cant click</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>can click</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [.not](https://api.jquery.com/not/) to exclude not desired table rows, code below shall do what you wish:

```
$('tr').not('thead tr').click(function () {
*** do stuff
});
```

**Suggestion:** from your samples it looks like you've been using common value for `id` attribute, that would be much better to use class instead as the id attribute is intended to be unique per element within whole html of the page.

**Good Luck :) !**

Comment: This will not work as a delegate, you need to do `:not()` within the selector.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this

```js
$('tr:not("thead tr")').on("click",function () {
      console.log("not thead");
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="upgrades">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>not clickable</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>clickable</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```